# How to convert SOQL query to SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby, salesforce, soql, restforce

I am working on SQL query, I have pre-created SOQL query, I am looking for a way to convert it to SQL query. The query is:

```
SELECT CronJobDetail.Name, Id, CreatedDate, State
FROM CronTrigger
WHERE CronjobDetail.JobType = 'bla bla'
    AND CronJobDetail.Name LIKE '%bla bla2%'
```

But It does not run on terminal when I try to create monitoring script in Ruby. The error that I get:

> (Got exception: INVALID_FIELD: No such relation 'CronJobDetail' on
>   entity 'CronTrigger'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be
>   sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference
>   your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. in
>   /Users/gakdugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/restforce-2.2.0/lib/restforce/middleware/raise_error.rb:18:in
>   `on_complete'

Do you have any idea how can I fix it and make it run on SQL?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code that doesn't work we need to see the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a relation without adding it to your `FROM` clause. Alternatively, if that's a custom field name, then do what the error message suggests you to do (add `__c` after the custom field name).

You probably want to do something like this:

```
SELECT CronJobDetail.Name, CronTrigger.Id, CronTrigger.CreatedDate, CronTrigger.State
FROM CronTrigger
    INNER JOIN CronJobDetail ON CronJobDetail.id = CronTrigger.foreign_id // this you have to do yourself
WHERE CronjobDetail.JobType = 'bla bla'
    AND CronJobDetail.Name LIKE '%bla bla2%'
```